# PHPmailer: Exclude input field from foreach loop

Tags: forms, input, foreach, phpmailer

I am happily running a contact form using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and recently added https://friendlycaptcha.com to minimize the amount of spam sent by bots through that form. I love the sleek implementation with no user interaction. The captcha is activated once you click the first input field in the form and auto-solves.
Unfortunately the captcha's solution (hidden input field) adds an enormous string to the e-mail that I would like to exclude.

How do I tell the foreach loop not to include the frc-captcha-solution in the mail that's composed?

```
    private function compose_mail($post)
{
    $content = "The following message has been received via contact form:\n\n";
    foreach($post as $name=>$value)
    {
        $content .= ucwords($name).": \t";
        $content .= "$value\n\n";
    }
    $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
}
```

This is the input field in the form that is generated and yields the long string.

```
<input name="frc-captcha-solution" class="frc-captcha-solution" type="hidden" value=".UNSTARTED">
```

An example of what I get is:

name:       Joe
e-mail:     joe@miller.com
address:    100 street
ZIP:        10100
place:      City
phone:      0123456789
msg:        This is a test message
Frc-captcha-solution:       f5e6874becd6758f456b78f6f1726e1d.YadsJVSp+/j0pyBNAQwtjQAAAAAAAAAA+eFoDacaj3c=.AAAAAJZoAQABAAAAQ5YAAAIAAADCJAUAAwAAAF9IAQAEAAAAj5cEAAUAAACwkQMABgAAAFcaAAAHAAAAfvIEAAgAAADvUwIACQAAAK/MAQAKAAAAm+MBAAsAAACU6AAADAAAAJZUAAANAAAA/dAEAA4AAABrSwEADwAAAC7mAAAQAAAAXFoDABEAAAD4UAEAEgAAACMEAAATAAAA3xcCABQAAABBHwMAFQAAAE6LAQAWAAAA1mwAABcAAAAmwwAAGAAAACIZBwAZAAAA6p4AABoAAADovwIAGwAAAFE/AAAcAAAA+d8BAB0AAACQ8gAAHgAAAO1fAgAfAAAAbtwCACAAAAA7EgEAIQAAABmWAQAiAAAA/ysAACMAAAAx0wIAJAAAAJsyBAAlAAAA6acBACYAAACATwAAJwAAAM/wBQAoAAAATLYJACkAAABT1AIAKgAAAMWWAwArAAAAzIAGACwAAAA3fwAA.AgAA

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, but one is to skip that name when it appears in your loop:

```php
private function compose_mail($post)
{
    $content = "The following message has been received via contact form:\n\n";
    foreach($post as $name => $value) {
        if ($name !== 'frc-captcha-solution') {
            $content .= ucwords($name).": \t";
            $content .= "$value\n\n";
        }
    }
    $this->mailer->Body = $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. Now the only thing left is to get rid of the $name value in the mail content, so that I only get the input data and not the name of each input field with it. When I remove the $content .= ucwords($name).": \t"; tho and only use &value the email gets sent, but the DIV replacement that gives the success message never shows up, so the user doesn't get feedback and it looks like the send button is without function :(

I put up a debug site here to test it:
http://pat.jakob-nawka.de/

Comment: You don't show the rest of your code, but I suspect you might be sending it as HTML when it only really needs to be plain text. Try calling `$mail->isHTML(false)`.